# How to correctly write a binomial distribution for a $50$ questions exam

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Using binomial distribution I want to know what is the chance of getting $70\%$ or greater in a $50$ question exam, each question having a true/false option to select from. What is the correct formula and can you show what the exact figures are in condition for $70\%$ or greater and show what each feature in the condition represents so I can use it to work out of scores (for example $60\%$ or greater, $50\%$ or greater).

I want the answer to be represented as a percentage so that I know know that the chances of getting $70\%$ or greater is $...\%$.

Thanks.

Comment: Should we assume you are guessing?  That implies you have a 50% chance of getting each question right and a 50% chance of getting each question wrong...If you're not guessing, say you have studied, then the probability of getting a question right may be higher since you prepared for the exam.  I'll assume your guessing.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Yes assume we are guessing, the research I am trying to conduct is that if a paper has more questions, then guessing will have less of an impact on gaining marks than if there were less questions.

Comment: How this question is different from your previous question? I cannot see a difference between those. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345831/probability-of-getting-70-in-exam-with-50-yes-no-questions

Comment: Since its binomial and you're guessing the only factors are the number of trials, which are questions here, and how many you have gotten right say x.  so x/n>=.70.  These are the only conditions.  You sum from x to n. In your case since n=50 and you need to know how many to get right to get a 70, you can show that you need 35 right to get at least a 70.  If it were 48 questions you would just need an x such that x/48=.7, in which that case it would be 34.

Comment: @Taro We are not sure if your formula is correct because you get 0.003 which times a hundred gets 0.3%, but we get 0.03 which is 3%. Been trying for hours but can't seem to sort it out

Comment: That is correct.  The probabilitiy of guessing at a 50 question T/F exam and receiving 70% or greater is .3%....which is why you study, not guess.

Comment: @user1394925 If you are good at computer rather than mathematics, this way of thinking may emotionally acceptable. http://aleph.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNj90KwiAUx-8F3-FcuhXliAgG9gh7gejCbVrCpuPooMdP56S80cP_43fU6GZAacd4mXlxGGB4OzMoSijpQMCVp9eoNATlA6taSiCe16q8j_Ik536U7R5iD36E5llljx8cqujhedQOwYKx8Im8l2Jd6fp5DyIXs70BVVjRZjGtEdDIKWEbXtcXShZ0fQak8k39A2R3oZjyA7gL6Gp-urWw5SO02avOAvTkZCjRxFzQ2LA500TJF8X4U-0=&lang=sage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if we can extend your question to a more general form. Consider that there is a paper with $N$ true-false questions, each worth $1$ mark. So the total marks for the paper is also $N$. A candidate takes the paper and he performs only guess work. Find the probability that he gets $k$ marks out of $N$.

Now, we know that this can be modelled with a binomial distribution with parameters $n=N$, $p=0.5$. As a probability student, I highly recommend you to explicitly write the probability distribution. Let $X$ be the number of questions answered correctly, out of $N$. You might have seen the notation $X$~ Bin$(N, 0.5)$ before.

Probability of answering $k$ questions correct is $$P(X = k) = \binom{N}{k} (0.5)^k (0.5)^{N-k} = \binom{N}{k}(0.5)^N$$

So you can just do a summation from here to solve. This is a special case for $p=0.5$.

Comment: Have you got the answer 0.03 and is that the percentage or is it 3%?

Comment: That is the correct answer.

Comment: So 3% is the answer. Thanks both of you

Comment: No, the answer is .33%.  You got an answer of .0033 so as a percentage it is 100x.0033 which is .33%.

Answer (score 1):

A binomial distribution takes the following form

$$P(K \ge k) = \sum_{j=k}^{n} \binom{n}{j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}$$

That is, the probability of getting at least $k$ successes of $n=50$ trials is given by the above formula, where $\binom{n}{j}$ is the binomial coefficient.

In your problem, $k$ is determined by the minimum test score you want.  For $60\%$, $k=30$, etc.  Because you are guessing, $p=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

A 70% or better implies that you have correctly answered 35 or more out of the 50 questions.  So P(X>=35).  Seeing as how you're most likely guessing, p=.5, (1-p)=q=.5, and n=50.  Let k=35, plug it in to Ron Gordon's formula and you should be able to go from here.

Comment: Hi, I have no idea how to go from there, m bro who does maths had a look at it and he is unsure on how to continue from there. IS there a way you can simply give us a formula and answer to see how to work out getting 70% or greater in the exam without caing about guessing or not. Then we can use this to work out other marks

Comment: do you know the binomial distribution?  I've given you p, q, and n...

Comment: Look at @Ron Gordon's formula.  That is how you procede.

Comment: I will have  look at Ron's answer, I don't do maths so I am relying on my bro, I do ICT